# Reading wrong data with HC-SR04 in arduino using FreeRTOS on ESP32

Tags: arduino, esp32, freertos, rtos

I am currently learning FreeRTOS and I wanted to integrate as a task the code from ultrasonic distance measure example and simply print it into the serial, but at some points it measures wrong.It jumps from 8 to 25 even tho I am not moving the object at the distance, it should be like 10-12 but not 25. If I am doing the code in a loop, it works.

[image]

```
    //Use only one core for complexity purposes
    #if CONFIG_FREERTOS_UNICORE
      static const BaseType_t app_cpu = 0;
    #else
      static const BaseType_t app_cpu = 1;
    #endif

    // defines pins numbers
    static const uint8_t trigPin = 2;
    static const uint8_t echoPin = 4;
    
    void task_distance(void *parameter)
    {
       while(1){
         long duration;
          int distance;

            // Clears the trigPin
          digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
          delayMicroseconds(2);

          // Sets the trigPin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
          digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
          delayMicroseconds(10);
          digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

          // Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
          duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);

          // Calculating the distance
          distance = duration * 0.034 / 2;

          // Prints the distance on the Serial Monitor
          Serial.print("Distance: ");
          Serial.println(distance);
    
           vTaskDelay(100 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS );
       }
        
    
    }
    
    void setup() {
    
    
      pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an Output
      pinMode(echoPin, INPUT); // Sets the echoPin as an Input
      Serial.begin(9600); // Starts the serial communication
    
    
      xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(task_distance, "Senzor distanta", 2048, NULL, 1, NULL, app_cpu);
    }
    void loop() {
    
    }
```

Comment: If the measurement relies on exact timing (delayMicroseconds ?) you should enclose the critical code part by a critical section. Otherwise an other task might get scheduled right in the middle of a measurement.

Comment: yes, that was the solution, thanks

Comment: @HS2 although that might make it work, it is a poor solution for a real-time system.  Critical sections should be avoided in general, but in any event should be short and deterministic.  Ultimately the Arduino library intended for a single threaded environment is unsuitable for real-time, multi-threaded environments.

Comment: It is a good idea to avoid floating point code especially on hardware without and FPU, and even if you have an FPU, you have to be certain that the RTOS preserves FPU registers in the context switch.  The use for floating point here is entirely unnecessary.  `distance = (duration * 17) / 100` will yield the same result, though `distance = (duration * 343) / 2000` will be more precise for 343m/s.  You used floating point, but even then lost precision by using 0.034 rather then 0.0343 - more/slower code for less precision is not a good trade-off.

Comment: @Clifford Basically you’re right regarding critical sections etc. and I’m aware of the cons and pros. It was just a proposal to make it working w/o redesigning the (broken) measurement method. Thanks !

Comment: Thank you Clifford for this information, I will make these changes soon.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that in the measure part, I needed to put taskENTER_CRITICAL and  taskEXIT_CRITICAL because was a very small delay.

Comment: For the critical section to work, your system must be doing something else not shown, because with only one thread, there is nothing to preempt the measurement.  Besides that the use of a critical section is often a sign of a failed design, and is particularly ill advised in this case, if this is intended to be a real-time system (rather implied by the use of an RTOS).

Comment: There is no advantage or useful purpose in using an RTOS for a single task.  You would do well from a design and real-time response point of view to separate the measurement from the presentation (i.e separate threads).  By having a single thread _and_ a critical section you are essentially preventing the RTOS from doing its job or anything useful.  Effectively the reason your code fails is because of the RTOS (or rather the way you have used it) and by defeating it it works!

Comment: The provided Arduino library is likely not RTOS friendly.  `pulseIn` for example will "busy-wait", and has non-deterministic execution time.  That will impact the performance and determinism of other lower priority threads, and will result in measurement errors if preempted by a higher priority thread or interrupt (hence the need for a critical section).  Using arduino libraries intended for single threaded execution will not always work well in an RTOS.  You should timestamp the trigger and wait for an interrupt for the return pulse. Or better, use a hardware input capture timer if available.

Comment: ... the MCPWM can be used to measure the return pulse time.  You need not then busy-wait, you could simply send the trigger pulse, start the input capture then delay.  The result will then be available in the input capture register after the delay.  The only critical section needed then would be the pulse generation which is deterministic, though no doubt that could be done with an _output compare_ timer, resulting in zero software overhead for the measurement.

Comment: I just wanted to be sure that it is working with just one sensor, I have another 2 sensors and I use the Bluetooth functionality. Every sensor is on a different thread, and Bluetooth is on a separate processor. I communicate between Bluetooth thread and sensors by a queue for each. I will definitely try your solution being more complex and optimal. I will try to post a video with all I did. Thank you!

Comment: There may be no no advantage in separate threads, you may have to trigger and wait on each sensor sequentially to avoid one receiving the echo from another.

Comment: I mean diferent sensors ( ambiental temperature and pointed temperature) mlx90614